# App crashes on iPhone but not on simulator

Tags: iphone, swift, debugging, crash, simulator

I'm using XCode 7.0b5 and created an Swift app. It runs fine on simulator but crashes on iPhone 4s when running independently (without cable).
How can identify where it crashes? I read about possible memory issues. I'm reading in a large textfile, so it needs nearly 200 MB of ram. How can I check it?

Comment: I found the text "Dirks.BookWorm failed to scene-create in time"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a memory problem with the iPhone 4S (200 mb for 4S is a lot). You should read the crash logs in Xcode.

In Xcode with the iPhone connected you can go to Window->Devices, select your phone and press 'View Device Logs'. You will see a list with all the last crashes of the apps and with the information of the crash.

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found a message, that "Dirks.BookWorm failed to scene-create in time". I need a lot of time for initialization. I read a large file, sort it etc. Do I have a time limit for it? How can I tell iOS, that I really need this time?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It is the run time.
I reduced the file sizes to 10% of the original and everything runs fine. So I can test it and "improve" it to the speed limit of the iPhone 4S. :-)

Comment: the same thing is happening with me since my project is quite old I have recently converted it from SOAP to Rest API 
since then it crashes on phone like iPHONE 5s and 7.
what should I do ?